# Instance of header view of navigation view in Android is always null

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am working with navigation view. I need to change design of header view programmatically according to a situation. But variable of the instance of header view is always throwing null exception. What is wrong with my code?

This is how I set header view in navigation view

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item"
        android:id="@+id/left_nv_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
```

This is the layout of my header view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header_view"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I instantiate header view and make changes to it in activity

```
  //I initialized navigation drawer and navigation view first 
   headerView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.header_view);
   headerView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

But it always throwing null pointer exception. How can I fix my code?

Comment: Please show the full `onCreate`. More specifically, what does the `setContentView` do?

Comment: Use the `NavigationView#getHeaderView()` method.

Comment: Thanks so much @Mike . That worked.

Comment: Can you post the answer please ? I want to upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NavigationView` takes some time to get its header `View`s inflated and laid out. Often, this will not be complete until after `onCreate()` has finished, but you can force it to happen immediately by using the `NavigationView#getHeaderView()` method.

After the headers have been successfully loaded, you would then be able to find them in the `Activity`'s `View` hierarchy, and your call to `findViewById()` wouldn't return null.